# Finding the floor value in an array

Tags: c#

Problem:

> Given an sorted array of N distinct integers, find floor value of input 'key'. Say, A = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10} and key = 7, we should return 6 as outcome.

How can I optimize my solution?

```
     private static int CalclualteFloorValue(int[] _sortedarray, int l, int r, int key)
        {
            if (_sortedarray[l] == key)
                return -1;




            int m = -1;

            while (l<=r)
            {
                 m = (r+l)/ 2;

                if (_sortedarray[m] == key)
                {
                    return  _sortedarray[m - 1];

                }
                else if (_sortedarray[m] < key)
                {
                    l = m+1;
                }
                else
                {
                    r = m-1;
                }
            }


            return _sortedarray[m];

        }

  int _floorValue = CalclualteFloorValue(_sortedarray, 0, _sortedarray.Length - 1,7);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the [`Array.BinarySearch<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) method? Or you need to reimplement it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of speed, your solution is about as optimized as it can get.  In terms of readability, your solution has much room for improvement.  I prefer readability over speed.  You should try to make your code as readable as possible, then, if you have performance issues, search for bottlenecks using a profiler and optimize them.  The method body of `CalclualteFloorValue` can be made into a one-liner, which happens to be slower but is much more readable.

```
private static int CalclualteFloorValue(int[] sortedArray, int key)
{
    return sortedArray.Last(x => x < key);
}
```

If you wish to keep the speed of your original solution and increase readability, there are many improvements you can make:

1. Have a consistent parameter naming convention.  `_sortedarray` has an underscore, but the other parameter names don't.  I prefer to only use underscores for variables declared within classes but not within methods.
2. `_sortedarray` should be lowerCamelCase.  That is, `sortedArray`.
3. If `l` will always be zero and `r` will always be array length - 1, declare them in the method body.  Don't make the method caller do unnecessary work.
4. Use descriptive variable names instead of single letters.

The beginning of the method will now look like this:

```
private static int CalclualteFloorValue(int[] sortedArray, int key)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = sortedArray.Length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `m`, `r` and `l` as your variable names.

I suggest spelling the name in full, not just the starting letter, like `middle`, `start`, `end` (or `middle`, `right`, `left`)

Comment: This does not answer the question about method optimization. This is better suited towards being a comment.

Comment: @WillSherwood  Reviewers may comment on any aspect of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're using -1 to indicate that the floor of the key is not in the array, but what if -1 *is* the floor of the key? Conflating indices and array elements in the return value is going to cause trouble.

The floor of `x` is the greatest value less than **or equal** to `x`.

Also, what happens when `key < sortedArray[l]`?

For the array `1, 2, 3`, here are the results I would expect, and the actual results:

```
key    expected    actual
0      (no floor)  1
1      1           -1
2      2           1
3      3           2
4      3           3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a standard problem. If you're doing CP, heed what others have said, but if you're doing development, there's a function called `lower_bound`. Use that.